# Remove tab bar background when using custom layer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbar, cashapelayer

[image]

I have created a custom rounded floating tab bar successfully but how can i removed the default tabbar (shown with arrow in the picture). I tried to set tabbar background to UIImage() and set background color to clear but it is still not working.
My code:

```
let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    guard let tabBar = tabBarController?.tabBar else {return}
    layer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 30,
                                                  y: tabBar.bounds.minY + 5,
                                                  //y: tabBar.bounds.minY - 28,
                                                  width: tabBar.bounds.width - 60,
                                                  height: tabBar.bounds.height - 24),
                              cornerRadius: (tabBar.frame.width / 2)).cgPath
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0)
    layer.shadowRadius = 25.0
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    layer.opacity = 1.0
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    
    tabBar.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 0)
```

Comment: Have you tried checking the superviews if any of them have background color?

Comment: @Aswath yes, none of them have background color

Answer (score 2):

Use the tab bar appearance:

```
        let app = UITabBarAppearance()
        app.backgroundEffect = .none
        app.shadowColor = .clear
        tabBar.standardAppearance = app
```

Comment: Tried this solution and still not working

Comment: Works for me, sorry.

Comment: Do you use storyboard or create ui programatically?

Comment: I started with the storyboard. But I don't see what difference it would make.

Answer (score 0):

**For All iOS Versions**

```
self.tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
self.tabBar.isTranslucent = false

// set a specific tab bar color
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    tabBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    tabBarAppearance.backgroundEffect = .none
    tabBarAppearance.shadowColor = .clear
    tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
    }
}
```